# How do I delete a custom variable keyword from a database?

Tags: mysql, sql

The database contains entries that resemble the following;

```
[caption id="attachment_2792" align="aligncenter" width="600"]<img class="size-full wp-image-2792" src="https://www.blabla.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Ultimate-Fishing-Simulator-5.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="337" /> Simple Keyword 1[/caption]
```

The output I want should be this way (remove Simple Keyword 1);

```
[caption id="attachment_2792" align="aligncenter" width="600"]<img class="size-full wp-image-2792" src="https://www.blabla.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Ultimate-Fishing-Simulator-5.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="337" /> [/caption]
```

Briefly;
I want to delete everything between /> [/ caption].

Comment: Is Simple Keyword 1 always going to be the final part of the string? Or anywhere in the tag?

Comment: Always before the caption. But it's a variable word. Example; Keyword 2

Comment: It is very some you check the index in string for /.> And </ caption and string remove it

Comment: Ok, so not specific keyword, but all text between the final `[/caption] tag` and the preceeding end tag `/>`

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Answer (score 1):

you could try using

```
  select concat(left(your_col, locate('/>', your_col) -1)
 ,right(your_col, length(your_col) - locate('[/caption]',your_col)+1 ))
 from your_table;
```

.

```
set @str ='[caption id="attachment_2792" align="aligncenter" width="600"]<img class="size-full wp-image-2792" src="https://www.blabla.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Ultimate-Fishing-Simulator-5.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="337" /> Simple Keyword 1[/caption]';

select concat(left( @str, locate('/>',  @str) -1)
       ,right( @str, length( @str) - locate('[/caption]', @str)+1 ))
```

for update your db you could use

```
update your_table  
select your_col =  concat(left(your_col, locate('/>', your_col) -1)
       ,right(your_col, length(your_col) - locate('[/caption]',your_col)+1 ))
```

Comment: My Table is 1y5D0_post and column is: post_content. I run this code; update 1y5D0_post  
select post_content =  concat(left(post_content, locate('/>', post_content) -1)
       ,right(your_col, length(post_content) - locate('[/caption]',post_content)+1 ))

But is not did not work correctly

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'select post_content =  concat(left(post_content, locate('/>', post_content) -1)
' at line 2

Comment: select   post_content = concat ??? ... you can't use select and assign to a column  .. remove post_content =   ...just select  concat(left(your_col, locate('/>', your_col) -1)
 ,right(your_col, length(your_col) - locate('[/caption]',your_col)+1 ))

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me;

```
UPDATE 1y5D0_posts 
SET post_content = 
CONCAT( 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, 
                       ' /> ', 
                       1), 
       SUBSTRING(post_content, 
                 LOCATE('[/caption]', 
                        post_content, 
                        LOCATE(' /> ',
                               post_content)
                        ) + 0)
      )
WHERE post_content LIKE '%/>%[/caption]%';
```